# Voltage regulator circuit increasing voltage when I connect a lower impedance load

Tags: power-supply, transistors, voltage-regulator

I found this topology for a voltage regulator using a LM 317 and a "current booster" PNP transistor:

[image: circuit]

So, I tested this same topology with a little change: I used a TIP36C for the transistor and used a 100 R resistance instead to avoid heating of the LM 317 regulator (and make the transistor conduce sooner). I used it with a 19 V source.

But, I found a problem that I couldn't yet reproduce in simulations: The voltage in the output is RISING when I connect a load. Why could that be?

For instance, if it's at 11 V and I connect a 11 ohm load it will rise to around 12 V. And I'm under the impression this rise takes a reasonable amount of time, like 0.5 s.

I already checked everything and nothing seemed wrong, except from the transistor itself.

When I measure it with a multimeter, I'm finding a 2.6 V base-emitter reverse breakdown voltage (while the forward voltage is around 0.7 V).

This seems off, I thought it should be around 5 V at least.

Could it be the transistor is bad and causing that behavior?

I tried considering that but still couldn't imagine how could this cause such behavior.

Comment: Put the meter in AC mode and report the AC voltage on the load

Answer (score 2):

It oscillates with both 10 Ohms and 100 Ohms at 11V/1A. The oscillation can be eliminated with a 220nF capacitor at the indicated location.
[image: oszc1]

[image: oszc2]

Comment: may I ask what simulator is that?

Comment: I just used Tina (v 9.3) now, but I have LTSpice, Tina-TI, and PSpice for TI 2020.
Depending on what I want to model, I always need another one.

Answer (score 0):

By increasing the resistor to 100 ohm all the output current is through the transistor so the regulator is out of the circuit. Change the resistor back to 10 ohm this way the transistor will conduct only when the output current is greater than 50mA.
If you increase the resistor to 22 ohm you may get only 25mA through the LM317

Comment: But the base-emitter on voltage of TIP36C is 4 V